# code for generating none repeating random numbers. Looks fine to me but when i run it gives me the same number

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Practice_assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] winning_numbers = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ;

        //The i++ for the first loop is in the second loop. I was trying to ensure it only goes to 
          the next value of the loop once a unique value has been gotten.
        for (int i=0; i<10;){
            int max = 99;
            int min = 1;
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            for (int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                if (j<i && winning_numbers[j]==randomNum){
                    break;
                }
                else if (j==i && i<10){
                    winning_numbers[i] = randomNum;
                    System.out.println(winning_numbers[i]+" ");
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `Random rand = new Random();` outside the loop. Never initialize `Random` in a loop. The default seed is based on the time. And modern computers are **fast**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve, I think you could use something like this:

```
public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] winning_numbers = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ;
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < winning_numbers.length; i++) {
            OptionalInt generatedInt = random.ints(1, 0, 100).findFirst(); // generates a stream of 1 number between 0 and 99 and gets the first (and only) one generated
            while (contains(winning_numbers, generatedInt)) { 
                generatedInt = random.ints(1, 0, 100).findFirst(); // while the generated number is already in the array, generate a new one
            }
           winning_numbers[i] = generatedInt.getAsInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(winning_numbers));
    }

    // this method will check if the given array already contains the generated int
    private static boolean contains(int[] arr, OptionalInt generatedInt) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(number -> generatedInt.getAsInt() == number);
    }

}
```

I ran it a couple of times and here are some outputs I generated with this code:

```
[52, 54, 21, 62, 47, 13, 94, 36, 82, 25]
[35, 37, 16, 81, 22, 71, 17, 94, 56, 8]
[51, 50, 80, 62, 18, 88, 1, 53, 44, 79]
[16, 95, 18, 66, 31, 4, 1, 55, 52, 26]
[4, 11, 65, 68, 22, 76, 95, 67, 35, 92]
[49, 87, 34, 88, 71, 57, 12, 76, 70, 78]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to generate an array of winning_numbers.  Here is one ways to do it.

- create a helper method to look for duplicate numbers and return true if a duplicate is found.
- then iterate over the array checking for the current random number and adding it if unique.
- note that `min`, `max`, and `rand` should be initialized outside the loop.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] winning_nummbers = new int[10];

int max = 99;
int min = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    // if does not contain a duplicate, then assign
    if (!contains(winning_numbers, randomNum)) {
        winning_numbers[i++] = randomNum;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(winning_numbers));
```

Prints something like this.

```
[46, 91, 5, 2, 42, 58, 74, 24, 53, 36]
```

The helper method.

```
public static boolean contains(int[] array, int v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to use streams you can do it like so using a `Random` instance.

- stream values form `min` to `max` inclusive.
- drop duplicates with distinct
- limit(10) limits to 10 values.
- put them in an array

```
int[] winning_numbers = rand.ints(min,max+1)
                         .distinct()
                         .limit(10)
                         .toArray();
```